# SQL Server-Group By

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Part which have a Part# and a Quote#. There can be multiple part# with same name and multiple same Quote#. For example:

Part Table

| Part# | Quote# |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | Q1 |
| P1 | Q2 |
| P1 | Q1 |
| P2 | Q2 |
| P3 | Q1 |
| P3 | Q2 |
| P3 | Q1 |

and I want the result of my sql query to be

| Part# | Quote# | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Q1 | 2 |
| P1 | Q2 | 1 |
| P2 | Q2 | 1 |
| P3 | Q1 | 2 |
| P3 | Q3 | 1 |

But I am unable to get the desired result and my query looks like

```sql
select partNo,
       quoteId
from part
where deleted_at is null
group by partNo, quoteId
order by partNo, quoteId
```

Comment: Why are you grouping at all when you have no aggregate functions? Aren't you just after a `COUNT`?

Comment: yeah, totally skipped it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but isn't it as simple as this?

```
select partNo, quoteId, count(*) as quantity
from part 
group by partNo, quoteId 
order by partNo, quoteId
```